# How can I use i18n strategy in nuxt3?

Tags: internationalization, locale, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

I use `@nuxtjs/i18n` with `nuxt3` and I need to use strategy `prefix_except_default`. But it doesn't work.

My code:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-beta.12",
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n'
  ],
})
```

`i18n.config.ts`

```
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      welcome: 'Welcome'
    },
    ua: {
      welcome: 'Ласкаво просимо'
    }
  },
  strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
  defaultLocale: 'en'
}))
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ENQi.gif)

I need

http://localhost:3000/

http://localhost:3000/ua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup/#nuxtconfigts), not all the configurations go in `i18n.config`, but only the ones related to vuei18n.

The correct syntax is the following:

- nuxt.config.js

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n'
  ],
  i18n: {
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    locales: [
      'en',
      'ua'
     ],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    vueI18n: './i18n.config.js'
  }
})
```

- i18n.config.js

```
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      welcome: 'Welcome'
    },
    ua: {
      welcome: 'Ласкаво просимо'
    }
  }
}))
```

See a working project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-7pcsz2).

On stackblitz the paths are not visible unless you manually input them, but if you reproduce the project locally it will work.